# Django-cms toolbar not showing on my project

Tags: django, django-cms

To begin with, I have a problem with djangocms toolbar. I can't make it show when I append `?edit` to the end of url.

`Django version = 1.8.4`
`Django-cms version = 3.1.3`
`python = 2.7`

What I think is the problem, is the fact that I have djangocms installed on a blog app from my entire project. I only want django-cms functionality on my `/blog app`

So, my project structure looks like this:

```
-project/
 -blog/
  -templates/
  -__init__.py
 -project/
 -static/
 -website/
 -manage.py
 -README.md
```

Now, I want to append toolbar to: `mywebsite:8000/blog?edit` but it's not working. Can't see any errors in shell console or web console.

**urls.py** (relevant part)

`url(r'^blog/', include('cms.urls')),`

The template part works as I can see the templates that I set in `settings.py` in `CMS_TEMPLATES`.

I also have `CMS_PERMISSION=False` (tried with `true` also), and the following to installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'console_admin',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'blog',
    'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'project',
    'adminplus',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'reversion',
    'treebeard',
)
```

I checked several tutorials from django-cms but unfortunately I had no success. Can anybody help me, please ? I really need to get this done.

Answer (score 3):

You need `{% cms_toolbar %}` in your (base) template in order to ensure the template gets displayed across your site.

It's usually best placed right after the `<body>` tag in your `base.html` file.

Also if you define `CMS_TOOLBAR_ANONYMOUS_ON` in your settings as False you need to login via `/admin/` before you can use `/?edit` to view the toolbar.

Comment: @Dex Do you define `CMS_TOOLBAR_ANONYMOUS_ON` in your settings? If it's set to `False` you need to login via `/admin/` before you can use `/?edit` to view the toolbar.